# Approximate a Sum using Integration by Parts

Tags: definite-integrals, summation, approximation

I would like to approximate the divergent sum
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{e^{\mu i}}{1+i}\ ,
$$
where $\mu >0$. I attempted to use integration by parts, arrived at
$$
 \int_0^n \frac{e^{\mu t}}{1+t} dt = e^{\mu n} \log{(1+n)} - \frac{1}{\mu}\int_0^n e^{\mu t}\log{(1 + t)} dt\ ,
$$
and promptly got stuck. Is there a way to proceed? Or perhaps a better approach?

Context for the curious: this sum would be the capital recovery factor in an investment appraisal where the return has a trend $\mu$, but where standard exponential discounting has been substituted with [hyperbolic discounting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_discounting?oldformat=true).

Comment: In the summation, is 'n' the final value, or the summation variable?

Comment: Do you mean $$\sum _{i=0}^n \frac{e^{i \mu }}{i+1}$$

Comment: The variable must be t. I do not see any t in the fraction or in upper bound of interval.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I've fixed the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a change of variables $t \to t/\mu -1$. Then, the Integral takes the for of the [exponential integral function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) with a pre-factor and different argument:
$$ \int_0^n \frac{e^{\mu t}}{1 + t} dt = e^{-\mu} \int_1^{\mu(n+1)} e^t/t~ dt = e^{-\mu} \Big( \text{Ei}[\mu(n+1)] - \text{Ei}[1] \Big)  $$

Does that help?

Alternatively:
We know that the exponential function is increasing very rapidly. So rapidly, in fact, that the integral over all values up to $x$ is about as large as $e^x$ itself. Maybe this holds for the sum as well:
$$\int_0^x e^{\mu t} dt \approx \mu^{-1} e^{\mu x} \overset{?}{\rightarrow} \sum_{i=0}^n e^{i \mu} \approx \mu^{-1} e^{\mu (n+1)}.$$
If so, then the $1/(1+i)$ should not change much:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{e^{\mu i}}{i+1} \approx \mu^{-1} \frac{e^{\mu (n+1)}}{n+2}. $$
I tried a few examples and it seems to give at least the right order of magnitude for $n\mu$ up to 100. That means about $50 \%$ error, but such deviations already appears when comparing $\int e^t dt$ and $\sum_i e^i$. So a better approximation can probably not be achieved through the integral but only by looking at the sum directly.

Comment: Thanks for this. This is indeed helpful since the Ei function appears to have several approximations.

Comment: That was my hope, but I have to admit that it is not easy to find one that does not rely on numerical results. If you find a good one, let me know!
But maybe I have an intuitive solution to this... I'll edit my answer.